# Retrieve value from CDATA

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, cdata

I am using java(JAXB) and i want to retrieve data from **CDATA**

```
<![CDATA[Need Help]]>
```

**Desired output**

```
Need Help
```

Can any body help me out. I tried several solutions.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Test0 {
    String e1;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String xml = "<root><e1><![CDATA[Need Help]]></e1></root>";
        Test0 t = JAXB.unmarshal(new StringReader(xml), Test0.class);
        System.out.println(t.e1);
    }
}
```

output

```
Need Help
```