# How to Get the data between CDATA tag in XML

Tags: java, xml, parsing

> ****I have got an assignment in which I hav an XML data in the
>   following format.****

```
Here is my XML 

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ilog.rules.studio.model.brl:ActionRule xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:ilog.rules.studio.model.brl="http://ilog.rules.studio/model/brl.ecore">
  <name>DDM_Washer_V10K_V1_FC_F3E2</name>
  <uuid>dd221315-a429-4a6b-9103-814ed624bf89</uuid>
  <locale>en_US</locale>
  <definition><![CDATA[if
    m2mAttributeName is "System_FaultCode"
    and m2mValueTypeString is "F3E2"
then
    set template to "DDM_Washer_V10K_V1_FC_F3E2" ;
    set alertName  to "SystemAlerts" ;]]></definition>
</ilog.rules.studio.model.brl:ActionRule>
```

**Now I want to get data which is between CDATA tag and particularly I want to get mnmAttributename i.e "SystemFaultCode" and m2mValueType String i.e. "F3E2. kindly suggest the way to parse it and get this data "**

Comment: It's just normal text contained in the <definition> element. Read it as if there was no CDATA markup whatsoever. CDATA is just a syntax trick, it isn't observable in the data model. (It serves to be able to type in `&` literally inside it, instead of having to escape it as `&amp;` and similar with other escaped chars.)

Comment: Can you attach a snippet code please.I will be very grateful to you.

Comment: You'll need to show more about the XML libraries you're using before I can show a suitable code snippet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42802202/how-can-i-parse-an-xml-file-with-html-tags-inside-cdata-section

Comment: I have two string  1."if
    m2mValueTypeInteger equals 1
    and m2mAttributeName is "Compartment_CycleState"
then
    set template to "DDM_Washer_V10K_V1_ClothesClean" ;
    set alertName to "ClothesClean" " and 2 "if
    m2mAttributeName is "System_FaultCode"
    and m2mValueTypeString is "F3E2"
then
    set template to "DDM_Washer_V10K_V1_FC_F3E2" ;
    set alertName  to "SystemAlerts". Can you help how can i fetch m2mvalueTypeString  i.e.1 and m2mAttribute value i.e. "Compartment_CycleState" from this two string.The position of them can vary

Comment: Please put code in your question. It's impossible to read the above, as you should have noticed. Also, I mentioned we need to know what is the XML library you want to use. So, you need to tell what is the XML library you're using.

Comment: XML libarary i am using is STAX.  Now two xml are

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <definition><![CDATA[if
    m2mValueTypeInteger equals 1
    and m2mAttributeName is "Compartment_CycleState"
then
    set template to "DDM_Washer_V10K_V1_ClothesClean" ;
    set alertName to "ClothesClean" ;]]></definition>
</ilog.rules.studio.model.brl:ActionRule>

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ilog.rules.studio.model.brl:ActionRule xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:ilog.rules.studio.model.brl="http://ilog.rules.studio/model/brl.ecore">
  <name>DDM_Washer_V10K_V1_FC_F3E3</name>
  <uuid>1f2bb019-63c9-4a9f-aed1-769e6a6e95a2</uuid>
  <locale>en_US</locale>
  <definition><![CDATA[if
    m2mAttributeName is "System_FaultCode"
    and m2mValueTypeString is "F3E3"
then
    set template to "DDM_Washer_V10K_V1_FC_F3E3" ;
    set alertName  to "SystemAlerts" ;]]></definition>
</ilog.rules.studio.model.brl:ActionRule>

Comment: I am clear with how we will data inside CDATA. Its just the two xml gives two different string.Now i have to write the standard logic to get m2mAttributeName which is "Component_Cycle State" in XML 1 and "System_FaultCode" in XML 2. Similarly I have to fetch m2mAttributeValue. But if you will observe the two xml are bit different. In xml1 attribute value is in starting but in xml 2 attributeName is in starting. I want to write logic so that every time i fetch the correct value. I hope i am clear. Please help me

Comment: Okay, well, now that you have extracted the content of the CDATA, extracting a subpart of it has nothing to do with XML nor CDATA. Time to close this question and open another.

Comment: Okay. So can you please help how can i extract the sub part of the data. I have already posted  what i want to achieve once i have got the data

Comment: no, open another question with relevant title and content, and no mention of XML. To sum up, obey the rules. I shouldn't have to insist so much on that.